# Woocommerce Admin Order Details - Show custom data on order details page

Tags: php, wordpress, content-management-system, woocommerce

I'm searching and trying it for 2 days with no success, please help.

I want to filter woocommerce orders to add additional details from db to order details page based on product attribute but I can't find the right woocommerce action/filter hook for this task.
Here suppose I've variable `$is_customized = false`;

If `$is_customized == true` then I need to add custom data from database to orders detail page.

**NOTE: I don't want to add additional meta box instead I want to change order detail table for:**

- Replacing the default Product image with the image stored in database
  and,
- Adding a div containing custom attributes below product name.

I've all these values in my variables but I can't figure out which action hook should I use.

I've attached an image for clarification.

[image]

**Just need to know if I can change / filter these order results and how ?**

I appreciate for your time and help.
Thanks

Comment: Like any other custom post type columns are handled via [`manage $post type posts columns`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/manage_$post_type_posts_columns) and [`manage $post type posts custom column`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/manage_$post_type_posts_custom_column). And in the case of orders the post type is `shop_order`.

Comment: Nevermind, I just looked more closely at your screenshot and it isn't what I was thinking. That said, it is a metabox, so at worst you could remove it, and add a modified version in its stead.

Comment: means there is no action/filter available to filter these results or customize it instead of rewriting the whole module ?

Comment: **manage_edit-shop_order_columns** and **manage_shop_order_posts_custom_column** these both add extra column to orders table but I want to add column in order edit page where the details of the specific order is listed.

Comment: You can see the hooks you have at your disposal in [`html-order-items.php`](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/admin/meta-boxes/views/html-order-items.php) and [`html-order-item.php`](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/admin/meta-boxes/views/html-order-item.php)

Comment: okay, thanks for the links I'll see and update here whether it works or not. Thanks

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Here's a start on how to display some extra data on the [`woocommerce_before_order_itemmeta`](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/admin/meta-boxes/views/html-order-item.php#L55) hook:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_order_itemmeta', 'so_32457241_before_order_itemmeta', 10, 3 );
function so_32457241_before_order_itemmeta( $item_id, $item, $_product ){
    echo '<p>bacon</p>';
}
```

I don't know how you are saving your data, so I can't make more a more precise suggestion. Keep in mind that immediately following that hook, anything you've saved as order item meta will automatically display.

Filtering the image is more difficult. I've found this [gist](https://gist.github.com/westonruter/5808015) as a start, but it requires some custom conditional logic as you don't want to filter the thumbnail everywhere, but only in orders.

**Edit:** Currently the best I can do for filtering the item thumbnails:

```
add_filter( 'get_post_metadata', 'so_32457241_order_thumbnail', 10, 4 );
function so_32457241_order_thumbnail( $value, $post_id, $meta_key, $single ) {
    // We want to pass the actual _thumbnail_id into the filter, so requires recursion
    static $is_recursing = false;
    // Only filter if we're not recursing and if it is a post thumbnail ID
    if ( ! $is_recursing && $meta_key === '_thumbnail_id' ) {
        $is_recursing = true; // prevent this conditional when get_post_thumbnail_id() is called
        $value = get_post_thumbnail_id( $post_id );
        $is_recursing = false;
        $value = apply_filters( 'post_thumbnail_id', $value, $post_id ); // yay!
        if ( ! $single ) {
            $value = array( $value );
        }
    }
    return $value;
}


add_filter( 'post_thumbnail_id', 'so_custom_order_item_thumbnail', 10, 2 );
function so_custom_order_item_thumbnail( $id, $post_id ){
    if( is_admin() ){
        $screen = get_current_screen();
        if( $screen->base == 'post' && $screen->post_type == 'shop_order' ){
            // this gets you the shop_order $post object
            global $post; 

            // no really *good* way to check post item, but could possibly save 
            // some kind of array in the order meta
            $id = 68;
        } 
    }
    return $id;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, its the exact thing which I'm actually looking for. Can you please tell me how I can replace image as well ? And I also need a filter for quantity here. Means I don't want to display quantity if the condition is true.

Comment: The more I look at it the more I think filtering the image will be *very* difficult and possibly requires some filters be added to WooCommerce. It is easy enough to do in general, but the `get_post_thumbnail_id()` function relies purely on the `$post_id` and there's currently no way that I can see to send the `$order_item` which is the version of the product that is unique that that particular order.

Comment: yes, let me explain. Actually its a designing tool and every customer will design his own product and obviously the product image will be different each time. I've successfully added custom data and image from session to cart and then orders but I'm just stuck here. The product image's name is in db and i can get it via order id but how to override ? That's the main point.

Comment: I understand your question. I built something years ago to combine WooCommerce with EZprints, which is the same concept you are describing. I'm telling you that it (to my knowledge) isn't currently possible. I've edited the answer to display what is the best I can do without modifying WooCommerce.

Comment: Okay thanks for your time. I'm going to implement this. I'll update here if it works or not. Thanks again and thanks to SOF community. Hope I can give you more votes. :)

Comment: Keep an eye on this [pull request](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/pull/9081). If it is merged into WooCommerce core, it will be easy to do what you are asking.

Comment: I've added that in my fav but isn't it effect to core functionality when updating wordpress ?

Comment: I don't understand your question. If that is added into WooCommerce you'll be able to filter the admin thumbnail directly in one of the next updates of WooCommerce. (or sooner if you patched WooCommerce yourself knowing the change has been approved)

Comment: No, its okay now. I've used the above method and its working fine. I just use **post_thumbnail_html** instead of **post_thumbnail_id** and got what I want. It' not effecting anything else and working absolutely correctly as required. Thanks

Comment: I skipped filtering `post_thumbnail_html` because if there is no thumbnail then I think Woo skips to a default image. But if your image always has a thumbnail then `post_thumbnail_html` can also work.

Comment: FWI- the filter that I proposed to WC has been merged in to core, so you could go that route in anticipation that it will eventually be official code.

Comment: The intro with the simple bacon example was so helpful, thank you